# How to push an array with comma between values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Good morning, need your help, I have the below function, which renders the color when the click function is triggered,
but the result is, it is going to concat only the values fetched.

```
state = {
    selectedColor: [],
}

  onlclickedSelectColor = (event) => { 
    const {selectedColor} = this.state;
    let color = event.target.value !== this.state.selectedColor
                      ? event.target.value : '';

      this.setState({
        selectedColor: selectedColor.concat(color),
      }, () => { console.log(selectedColor) });  

  }


render () {

return (
                           // this map is from backend
                            {colors.map((clr, index) => (
                              <TableRow hover tabIndex={-1}>
                                <TableCell key={`cell-${index}`} style={{ paddingRight: 0, paddingLeft: 0  }}>
                                                                   
                                    <Checkbox
                                      checked={selectedColor.includes(color[`colorID`])}
                                      onChange={(e) => {this.onlclickedSelectColor(e, color)}}
                                      

                                    />
                                  
                                </TableCell>

                              </TableRow>
                              ), this)}

)

}
```

the result in the console when i click the function is this:
["RedBlueGreen"]

My desired result is this:

["Red", "Blue", "Green"]

Thanks

Comment: `selectedColor.join(", ")` ?

Comment: `event.target.value !== this.state.selectedColor` how can an array match a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `selectedColor.concat(color)`, you can use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to push an element to the array.

```js
this.setState({ selectedColor: [...this.state.selectedColor, color] })
```

Comment: it show an error, selectedTransactor.push is not a function

Comment: Try this: `this.setState({ selectedColor: [...this.state.selectedColor, 'new value'] })`

Comment: Genius Man!! just needed to change the 'new value' to 'color', Thanks man!